# gnome-settings-daemon doesn't apply themes, unless I kill it and start it manually

Tags: 10.10, panel, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 10.10 forgets desktop theme.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/ubuntu-10-10-forgets-desktop-theme)

**UPDATE:** It looks like i'm experiencing [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/574296) where Ubuntu can't do themes on fast computers (e.g. SSD drive and/or i7 CPU).

**UPDATE:** I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 x64 on a SECOND brand new computer. I logged in for the first time, and themes displayed ok, I then activated the recommended Nvidia driver, rebooted, and the themes don't display, same issue.  If I kill "gnome-settings-" then run "sudo gnome-settings-daemon" the themes work again (until I reboot).

I just installed Ubuntu 10.10, and after activating the Nvidia drivers, and Ubuntu seems to have lost the theme, it looks like old school 9.04 or something (but some parts, like the window title/menu bars look new)

Jorge suggested in the comments that: "This isn't a theme issue, you're gnome-system-daemon is likely crashing. Is this persistent across reboots?"

Looking back, I think the problems started when I tried to start using dual monitors.  I ran the "NVDIA X Server Settings" applet, and accidentally chose "Separate X screen (requires X restart)" at which point I got different displays on each monitor, but each had their own panel and applications menu etc.  I've since switched to "TwinView" which is the one I think I should have chosen originally.

Running *gnome-settings-daemon* produced the following output:

```
 alex@alex-pc3:~$ – alex@alex-pc3:~$ gnome-settings-daemon

 ** (gnome-settings-daemon:11554): WARNING **: Failed to acquire org.gnome.SettingsDaemon 
 ** (gnome-settings-daemon:11554): WARNING **: Could not acquire name
```

If I run `sudo gnome-setttings-daemon`, then it seems to work, my panel and windows and icons etc all look modern as per the latest theme.   However, after restarting the problem is back, so I guess I can manually run gnome-settings-daemon.

I get this output from gnome-settings-daemon:

```
alex@alex-pc3:~$ sudo gnome-settings-daemon
alex@alex-pc3:~$ 
** (gnome-settings-daemon:1978): WARNING **: Grab failed for some keys, another application may already have access the them.

** (gnome-settings-daemon:1978): WARNING **: Clipboard manager is already running.
Unable to find a synaptics device.
```

I rebooted again, I typed "ps - A | grep settings" and found one process running called "gnome-settings-", so it looks like gnome-settings-daemon is running, but not working?

Debug Output:

```
alex@alex-pc3:~$ sudo killall gnome-settings-daemon
alex@alex-pc3:~$ gnome-settings-daemon --nodaemon --debug

** (gnome-settings-daemon:8325): WARNING **: Unknown option --nodaemon
alex@alex-pc3:~$ gnome-settings-daemon --no-daemon --debug
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Successfully connected to D-Bus
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting settings manager
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading settings plugins from dir: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/media-keys.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Media keys' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/media-keys.gnome-settings-plugin' location='media-keys'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/mouse.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Mouse' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/mouse.gnome-settings-plugin' location='mouse'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/xrdb.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='X Resource Database' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/xrdb.gnome-settings-plugin' location='xrdb'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/keyboard.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Keyboard' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/keyboard.gnome-settings-plugin' location='keyboard'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/sound.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Sound' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/sound.gnome-settings-plugin' location='sound'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/typing-break.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Typing Break' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/typing-break.gnome-settings-plugin' location='typing-break'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/housekeeping.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Housekeeping' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/housekeeping.gnome-settings-plugin' location='housekeeping'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/ubuntuone.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Ubuntu One' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/ubuntuone.gnome-settings-plugin' location='ubuntuone'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/clipboard.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Clipboard' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/clipboard.gnome-settings-plugin' location='clipboard'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/xrandr.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='XRandR' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/xrandr.gnome-settings-plugin' location='xrandr'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/font.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Font' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/font.gnome-settings-plugin' location='font'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/xsettings.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='X Settings' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/xsettings.gnome-settings-plugin' location='xsettings'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/keybindings.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Keybindings' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/keybindings.gnome-settings-plugin' location='keybindings'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/background.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Background' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/background.gnome-settings-plugin' location='background'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading plugin: /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/a11y-keyboard.gnome-settings-plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsPluginInfo: name='Accessibility Keyboard' file='/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/a11y-keyboard.gnome-settings-plugin' location='a11y-keyboard'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c0cd40 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libxrandr.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdXrandrPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdXrandrPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdXrandrPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating xrandr plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting xrandr manager
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated xrandr
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin xrandr: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c0d000 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libxsettings.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GnomeXSettingsPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GnomeXSettingsPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeXSettingsPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating xsettings plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting xsettings manager
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: xft_settings_set_xresources: orig res 'Xft.dpi: 96
Xft.antialias: 1
Xft.hinting: 1
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: xft_settings_set_xresources: new res 'Xft.dpi: 96
Xft.antialias: 1
Xft.hinting: 1
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated xsettings
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin xsettings: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin font: inactive
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c0d280 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libsound.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdSoundPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdSoundPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdSoundPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating sound plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting sound manager
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering directory monitor for /home/alex/.local/share/sounds
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering directory monitor for /usr/share/gnome
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering directory monitor for /usr/local/share/
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering directory monitor for /usr/share/
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated sound
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin sound: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c11f20 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libkeyboard.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdKeyboardPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdKeyboardPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdKeyboardPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating keyboard plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated keyboard
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin keyboard: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c11f70 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/liba11y-keyboard.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdA11yKeyboardPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdA11yKeyboardPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdA11yKeyboardPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating a11y_keyboard plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated a11y-keyboard
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin a11y-keyboard: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c57400 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libmouse.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdMousePlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdMousePlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdMousePlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating mouse plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated mouse
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin mouse: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c57450 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libkeybindings.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdKeybindingsPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdKeybindingsPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdKeybindingsPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating keybindings plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting keybindings manager
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated keybindings
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin keybindings: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin xrdb: inactive
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c574a0 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libbackground.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdBackgroundPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdBackgroundPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdBackgroundPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating background plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting background manager
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated background
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin background: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c574f0 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libmedia-keys.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdMediaKeysPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdMediaKeysPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdMediaKeysPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating media_keys plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated media-keys
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin media-keys: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c69400 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libclipboard.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdClipboardPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdClipboardPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdClipboardPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating clipboard plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated clipboard
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin clipboard: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c69450 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libtyping-break.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdTypingBreakPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdTypingBreakPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdTypingBreakPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating typing_break plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting typing_break manager
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated typing-break
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin typing-break: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c694a0 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libubuntuone.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdUbuntuOne
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdUbuntuOne
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated ubuntuone
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin ubuntuone: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsModule 0x1c694f0 initialising
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Loading /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libhousekeeping.so
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Registering GsdHousekeepingPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Creating object of type GsdHousekeepingPlugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GsdHousekeepingPlugin initializing
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Activating housekeeping plugin
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting housekeeping manager
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: housekeeping: will tidy up in 2 minutes
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: GnomeSettingsManager: emitting plugin-activated housekeeping
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Plugin housekeeping: active
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting keyboard manager
[1289226919,000,xklavier.c:xkl_engine_start_listen/]  The backend does not require manual layout management - but it is provided by the application
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting a11y_keyboard manager
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Starting media_keys manager
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Not a valid shortcut: ''
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: adding key filter for screen: 0

** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): WARNING **: Clipboard manager is already running.
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating client: index=0 name='ConsoleKit Session /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating client: index=2 name='NetworkManager Applet'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating client: index=3 name='ayatana.indicator.sound'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating client: index=4 name='File Manager'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating client: index=5 name='gtk-window-decorator'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating client: index=10 name='XSMP Session on gnome-session as 10265a88872e6e751d128896818869836100000014480036'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating client: index=11 name='Panel'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating client: index=25 name='ALSA plug-in [TweetDeck]'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating client: index=29 name='Rhythmbox'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating client: index=30 name='GNOME Volume Control Media Keys'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating sink: index=0 name='alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo' description='Internal Audio Analog Stereo' map='front-left,front-right'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating source: index=0 name='alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor' description='Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Stereo'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Updating source: index=1 name='alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo' description='Internal Audio Analog Stereo'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Udpating card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 (index: 0 driver: module-alsa-card.c):
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Profile 'output:analog-stereo': 0 sources 1 sinks
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Profile 'output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo': 1 sources 1 sinks (Current)
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Profile 'output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo': 1 sources 1 sinks
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Profile 'output:iec958-stereo': 0 sources 1 sinks
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Profile 'output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo': 1 sources 1 sinks
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Profile 'output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo': 1 sources 1 sinks
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Profile 'input:analog-stereo': 1 sources 0 sinks
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Profile 'input:iec958-stereo': 1 sources 0 sinks
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Profile 'off': 0 sources 0 sinks
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'alsa.card' = '0'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'alsa.card_name' = 'HDA Intel'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'alsa.long_card_name' = 'HDA Intel at 0xfbff8000 irq 52'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'alsa.driver_name' = 'snd_hda_intel'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'device.bus_path' = 'pci-0000:00:1b.0'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'sysfs.path' = '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'device.bus' = 'pci'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'device.vendor.id' = '8086'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'device.vendor.name' = 'Intel Corporation'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'device.product.id' = '3b56'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'device.product.name' = '5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'device.form_factor' = 'internal'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'device.string' = '0'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'device.description' = 'Internal Audio'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'module-udev-detect.discovered' = '1'
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG:  Property: 'device.icon_name' = 'audio-card-pci'
Unable to find a synaptics device.
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Performing delayed syncdaemon init
** (gnome-settings-daemon:8326): DEBUG: Syncdaemon not running, waiting for it to start in NameOwnerChanged
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Alex How did you install it? Did you upgrade or use an existing `/home`?

Comment: Completely fresh install on brand new hard drive (brand new computer).  The panel looked fine before the reboot for the Nvidia drives.

Comment: I'm using dual monitors, "Twinview" in nvidia-settings

Comment: Is it only the panel or are all the programs using the default gnome theme?. Please open Nautilus and check.

Comment: hmm, it looks like the menubars of windows are fine, but the rest of the window is not. I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: Whats Nautilus?

Comment: @Alex The file browser, you have it open in your screenshot :P

Have you tried changing themes?

Comment: Yes, I tried changing themes. The odd thing is, when I open the 'appearance' applet, it says I am on a custom theme, then I choose "ambiance", and close it, then reopen it and its back on custom.

Comment: I haven't tried rebooting, I will try that in a bit and report back.  How do I find out if the gnome-system-daemon is crashing? Use 'ps' to check processes?

Comment: @AlexBlack Not sure, if rebooting fixes it we should adapt this question to figure out how we can do that.

Comment: I just rebooted, no change, the problem persists.

Comment: Any ideas @Jorge?

Comment: This is usually caused by a gnome-settings-daemon plugin, only problem is I fixed this on my own system over a year ago... so I need more information to pinpoint the plugin.

Comment: Any suggestions Roland?

Comment: Can you please [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) the output of `killall gnome-settings-daemon ; gnome-settings-daemon --no-daemon --debug`?

Comment: After reading your comment about the "Custom" theme theme I'd also like to see the output of `gconftool-2 --get /apps/metacity/general/theme /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme` and `sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --get /apps/metacity/general/theme /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme`.

Comment: output of gconftool-2 is "Ambiance Ambiance" (two separate lines)

Comment: Same for "gdm gconftool-2 ..."

Comment: I added the output for gnome-settings-daemon --no-daemon --debug to the original question

Comment: Both looks fine as far as I can tell. :-(

Comment: Damn. :( How about my other comment back to you re root-owned files in the other answer?

Comment: '.gvfs' is owned by my user on my systems, but I don't think that's the problem. (You can run `sudo chown alex:alex ~/.gvfs` to correct that.)

Comment: It's beginning to sound like you need to try reinstalling gnome-settings-daemon, or see if uninstalling the nvidia driver makes the problem go away.

Comment: anyone know what this is? "Unable to find a synaptics device." looks like it's trying to find a touchpad!

Comment: How does one reinstall gnome-settings-daemon? Uninstalling the nvidia driver sounds like a good idea, I'll try that later today.

Comment: According to "ls -la", the .gvfs folder is already owned by alex.. and I tried to chown it anyways, and got this: alex@alex-pc3:~$ sudo chown alex:alex /home/alex/.gvfs/
[sudo] password for alex: 
chown: cannot access `/home/alex/.gvfs/': Permission denied
alex@alex-pc3:~$

Comment: @Roland Taylor: it's a harmless message (that is already fixed [upstream](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-settings-daemon/commit/?id=fd4722b40351a3bfc1793fb4ec56e8a5a406786a)).

Comment: if you try to `rm -rf ~/.gvfs` does it allow you to remove it?

Comment: Just make sure that there's nothing mounted in that directory (so it's empty) before trying to delete it!

Comment: No such luck.. alex@alex-pc3:~$ sudo rm -rf .gvfs/
rm: cannot remove `.gvfs/': Is a directory
alex@alex-pc3:~$ sudo rmdir .gvfs/
rmdir: failed to remove `.gvfs/': Device or resource busy
alex@alex-pc3:~$

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry - the `find` command below said "Permission denied" and didn't show it as owned by root (uid 0). If `ls -al` says that this folder is owned by your user as you say, then everything's fine. Back to your problem: what happens if you choose another theme than 'Ambiance' in gnome-appearance-properties? Does it still show 'Custom' when you open it? When you select 'Ambiance', do you see such a message: http://img.xrmb2.net/images/457482.png ?

Comment: When I first log in, and experience the problem, gnome-appearance-properties says the theme is custom.  If I then kill gnome-settings-daemon, and start it manually, the theme then shows up, and if I run gnome-appearance-properties it says the theme is Ambiance. No, I haven't seen the msg you screencapped.

Comment: `ls -l /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop` - does this file exist? Are its permissions '-rw-r--r--'? I temporarily removed that file and have pretty much what you are describing. Else I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yes the file exists - when I login the process is running.. just not working :) I'll try uninstalling the nvidia driver and see if that helps.

Comment: alex@alex-pc3:~$ ls -l /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 291 2010-10-05 06:21 /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop

Comment: @AlexBlack As people keep asking you for feedback put the results of everything you're trying in your question, this way new people looking at the question get all the information right away instead of digging through the comments.

Comment: I just setup another brand new computer, with a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.10 x64.  First thing I did was install the Nvidia drivers, and the same issue occurred.