# Window theming not working

Tags: 10.10, nvidia, gtk, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

I've dual monitors (1920x1080 + 1920x1200) running on a nVidia GeForce 9800 GT.
This is a fresh Ubuntu 10.10 install running the default Ambiance theme.

I'm finding that the theme fails to load on any of the panel or window decorations resulting in the standard GTK grey.  The window boarders however are fine.

This occurs on all themes I've tried, I've also tried erasing all my profile settings and it still occurs (via creating a new user).

Please see screenshot: 
[image]

Can anyone point me to either a bug number or a fix for this please?

Thanks

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11406/gnome-settings-daemon-doesnt-apply-themes-unless-i-kill-it-and-start-it-manuall

Comment: Thanks!  Starting gnome-setttings-daemon fixes it.  Now to fix the real solution :)