# Nautilus is theme-less unless I run it as root

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, themes

My system is using the Ambiance theme in Ubuntu Natty. Everything works correctly except for Nautilus, which appears to have been deprived from its theme.
[image: Grey nautilus doesn't look healthy]

Can anyone help me restore it to the default Ambiance theme? (I've tried setting other themes but Nautilus is still grey)

If I open Nautilus with 'sudo' from the terminal, this bug isn't present and the theme is shown correctly.

I thought the [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)  answer would solve my problem, but after restarting, the theme-less Nautilus is back.

Something I noticed is that this problem is present in Nautilus and with Nautilus only.
As I said, if I run Nautilus as root the problem isn't present, only when running Nautilus as a normal user

Comment: I think you probably messed the own of some configurations files. I will search a solution.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme , http://askubuntu.com/questions/11406/gnome-settings-daemon-doesnt-apply-themes-unless-i-kill-it-and-start-it-manuall

Comment: I bet after running it with sudo that some of the config files now belong to root and your user account can't access them.

Comment: Is there any way to reset this Nautilus configuration? I don't mind using the default theme...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after searching around. [Adding a delay to `gnome-settings-daemon` when logging in corrected the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme/21901#21901)

Comment: This also shows up in the Linux Mint 11 known issues: http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_katya.php

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your icons theme?

Instructions:

**1)** Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `gnome-appearance-properties`

**2)** Go to "Theme" and click "Customize".

[image]

**3)** Go to "Icons" and choose one.

[image]

Comment: I just tried, I can change the icons but nautilus is still theme-less. Please see my update

Answer (score 1):

change the theme as root and put the themes you want in root.. this works for me..

in otherwords  become root and bring up your customization and select your theme or just download ubuntu tweak and have it fix the root theme bug

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely some kind of configuration issue going on.  Currently it seems like root and your login have different settings for themes.

Try running gksu gnome-appearance-properties

If you already see your default theme in there, and it isn't selected, all you need to do is select it.

if you don't see your theme in there, it will explain why root defaults to another theme.  Then you should check if your default theme is install at /usr/share/themes/  or simply install them again to that location.

if it's there and it's already selected, or selecting it doesn't make a difference, then still check your /usr/share/themes/ folder to see if the files are missing or broken or have wrong permissions....  hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found great solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1483838):

```
rm -vr ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus && killall nautilus
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah that fixed it for me

```
mv ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus.old && killall nautilus
```

..if it helps the last time I remember it was ok was the day before I 'discovered' dconf, so assume I broke it with that - or it was a coincidence.